# How to run a drupal application in github?

Tags: 7

I am trying to setup Drupal Application in **Github** and was able to  successfully setup the instance and moved the project to github.

Can anyone help me with as **how to execute a drupal application in github**,as I am finding tools to run html files but executing a drupal files seems to be a tedious task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not execute Drupal in Github, just because Drupal requires a server running PHP, which isn't supported by github.

> Github Pages is not a full-featured web host. It will not execute PHP, or any other arbitrary code.
>   [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837946/how-to-publish-php-page-instead-of-html-at-github-to-demo-some-php-content)

You could convert your Drupal site into a static site and upload it on github, but the website would not be dynamic anymore. If you decide to do this, you could host it using [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/), but you would not be executing Drupal; instead, you would be going to show a static version of your Drupal website.

If you wish to add a static version of your website for Drupal 7, you can look at the [Static Generator module](https://www.drupal.org/project/static). If you are running Drupal 8, you can use `wget --mirror http://example.com` and this will provide copy of your site's HTML.